# How can I use my own custom system settings in e-mail templates?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configuration, email-templates, variables

I have this custom configuration in my `system.xml`:

```
<system>
    <section id="general">
        <group id="store_information">
            <field id="support_phone" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="21" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Support Phone Number</label>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

And I want to use this in my e-mail templates. So naturally, I try something like:

```
{{config path="general/store_information/support_phone"}}
```

Now this doesn't render the variable. which makes sense. This was also a security issue in Magento 1 since it would allow you to peek into system configuration settings, like API keys and stuff. So I have to include these parameters. Now I've added to my `di.xml` the setting to the config exclude list and the source model used by the email module:

```
<type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Export\ExcludeList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configs" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="general/store_information/support_phone" xsi:type="string">1</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables">
    <plugin name="custom_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables"/>
</type>
```

But still it doesn't work. So where is the setting so I can whitelist certain configuration settings to be used in e-mail templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. In my source model I hooked into the `toOptionArray()`-method, but this had to be the `getData()`-method:

```
public function afterGetData(\Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables $subject, $result)
{
    $result = array_merge($result, [
        [
            'value' => 'general/store_information/support_phone',
            'label' => __('Support Phone Number')
        ],
    ]);

    return $result;
}
```

Why? Because the filter used by the e-mail module uses the `getData()`-method to determine whether or not a config setting is allowed to be used. See `\Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter::isAvailableConfigVariable()` for more details.

Comment: great solution, pulled me out of a pickle!